# Ignore a directory most of the time with find file in project

Tags: find-file

I have a directory structure like this:

```
a
  src
  target
b
  src
  target
c
  src
  target
    generated_source_files
    x
    y
    z
```

When I run `ffip`, I usually want to ignore looking for files in the target directories.  However, the `c` module generates source files that I sometimes want to look at, which are in `target/generated_source_files`.  Is there a way to exclude a/target and b/target but include c/target/generated_source_files?  Ideally, it would also exclude c/target/x.

Eventually, `d` and `e` will be added at the root level, so I would like a solution that does not explicitly mention `a` and `b`.  Explicitly mentioning `c` is fine.

I see `ffip-prune-patterns` which would let me exclude *all* target directories, but then I miss the generated_source_files directory.

I could try setting `ffip-project-root-function` to return the string `"a/src b/src c/src c/target/generated_source_files"` which would work when passed to `find`, but I'm not sure if the code tries to uses that to resolve relative paths somewhere.